# Accessing key values of a JSON

Tags: python, json

```
{
    "meta": {
        "shared_betslip_id": "30110601",
        "bet_id": "",
        "profile_id": "5583397",
        "code": "PHdWGc",
        "product_type": "PREMATCH"
    },
    "data": [{
            "parent_match_id": "32679869",
            "sub_type_id": "1",
            "outcome_id": "1",
            "odd_key": "BURNLEY",
            "special_bet_value": "",
            "odd_value": "2.65",
            "odd_def": "{$competitor1}",
            "match_id": "3134426",
            "game_id": "56545",
            "home_team": "BURNLEY",
            "away_team": "SOUTHAMPTON",
            "start_time": "2022-04-21 21:45:00",
            "name": "1x2",
            "sport_id": "14",
            "valid": "1"
        }, {
            "parent_match_id": "27965818",
            "sub_type_id": "1",
            "outcome_id": "2",
            "odd_key": "draw",
            "special_bet_value": "",
            "odd_value": "3.40",
            "odd_def": "draw",
            "match_id": "3206302",
            "game_id": "27527",
            "home_team": "LEVANTE",
            "away_team": "SEVILLA",
            "start_time": "2022-04-21 20:00:00",
            "name": "1x2",
            "sport_id": "14",
            "valid": "1"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Here are your picks."
}
```

how can i get the odd value using python. Have tried using json.loads but its giving an error raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: You aren't working with JSON at all. You have a Python `dict` object. JSON is a text-based serialization format. Now, a JSON  could be *deserialized into* that dict, but that doesn't make it JSON. Note, you haven't provided a [mcve]

Comment: "Have tried using json.loads but its giving an error" This is because what you have is **already** the loaded data, which is a **perfectly ordinary** Python `dict` containing more `dict`s and `list`s. "how can i get the odd value using python" You do this the **exact same way** that you would if you had gotten this same data **by any other route**.

Comment: `variable['data'][i]['odd_value']`

Answer (score 1):

just the odd values, as a list:

`odd_values = [ entry for x in example.get("data", [{}]) if (entry := x.get("odd_value")) ]`